# send a shell command or something similar to a running android app via Android Studio

Tags: android, shell, android-studio, kotlin

given an app with some public functions. how can I invoke those functions when the app is running via some input I write into android studio. some kind of a shell maybe?

```
fun foo1() = doesSomeFoo1()
fun foo2() = doesSomeFoo2()
fun foo3() = doesSomeFoo3()

...

//this runs every 2 seonds somewhere or when it gets notified that this kind of input was recieved
when (someInputBufferOrSomething.recievedInputFromAndroidStudio) {
    "execute foo1" -> foo1()
    "execute foo2" -> foo2()
    "execute foo3" -> foo3()
}
```